# Flatnotebook ignores all styles

Tags: python, wxpython

In the following sample program I can't seem to get the notebook control to use the styles I tell it to use. Despite the `FNB_HIDE_ON_SINGLE_TAB`, `FNB_NO_NAV_BUTTONS` and `FNB_X_ON_TABS` styles I still see the navigation buttons and a single tab with no close button. It's the same for all styles I've tried, they're all completely ignored.

I'm running this on Ubuntu 11.10, python 2.7.2 and wxPython 2.8.11 if it matters

```
import wx
import wx.lib.flatnotebook as FNB

class TabCtrl(FNB.FlatNotebook):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        windowstyle = FNB.FNB_HIDE_ON_SINGLE_TAB|FNB.FNB_NO_NAV_BUTTONS|FNB.FNB_X_ON_TAB
        super(TabCtrl, self).__init__(parent, style=windowstyle)

        self.pages = []

        self.pages.append(wx.Panel(self))
        self.AddPage(self.pages[0], 'Test')

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.tabs = TabCtrl(self.panel)

        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(vgap=8, hgap=8)
        sizer.Add(self.tabs, (0, 0), (10, 30), wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.AddGrowableCol(29)
        sizer.AddGrowableRow(9)

        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.panel.Fit()
        self.SetInitialSize()

class App(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(App, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.frame = MainFrame(None, title='Test')
        self.frame.Show()

app = App()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FNB_NO_NAV_BUTTONS and FNB_X_ON_TABS both work on my machine (using the wxPython demo) using wxPython 2.8.12, Windows 7, Python 2.6. When it comes to anything in the AGW widget set, I highly recommend downloading the latest version from SVN. I know the author of that library and he's always updating it and fixing bugs, so updating to the latest in SVN is usually worth it.

EDIT: I was looking at this again and I think you're putting at least some of those flags in on the wrong parameter. There's an "agwStyle" argument in FlatNotebook too and I'm thinking that's where some or all of those FlatNotebook-related flags should be applied to:

```
super(TabCtrl, self).__init__(parent, agwStyle=windowstyle)
```

Comment: That is very strange, because it doesn't work for me with Win 7, Python 2.6.6 and wxPython 2.8.12. And I'm not sure how to get the latest version from SVN, and it's not much use if I can't get it to work with the stable version anyway. Preferably should work with a few older versions too, but I can live with just the latest stable version.

Comment: Does it work in the wxPython demo? That's what I used to test with. You might contact the guys on the wxPython mailing list. The author of AGW is on there and is quite helpful.

Comment: The only demo I could find with tabs didn't seem to use the flatnotebook class. If you can find one that works with the flatnotebook and point me to it, then it should be possible to figure out what it does differently, I assume?

Comment: Open the demo, go to the search at the bottom left and type flatnotebook. Run the demo. That's all I did.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I was looking through the source directory manually. I tried that, but it still doesn't work (Win 7, Python 2.6.6, wxPython 2.8.12), when I select a style in the menu nothing happens.

Comment: Try asking on the wxPython mailing list then. The author of wxPython and the author of AGW hang out there. I'm sure they'll be able to help.

Comment: I don't know, can I just direct them here? I guess I'll just give up and use the plain wxNotebook or something. Or dump the project in the shredder. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: Of course you can tell them to look at this page. I don't know why you wouldn't want to get help from them though. I'm sure it's something simple. Now that I look at it again, I think those styles you're using might have to go in as styles for the agwStyle flag instead of the normal style flag.

Comment: Ahah! That's it, agwStyle did the trick. Thanks :) And it's not that I wouldn't want help from them, I just... don't know, mailing lists always bothered me for some reason and I was getting a little frustrated at the whole thing

Comment: Hmm. I thought there may be some different parameter for the styles, but after seeing some examples I was not convinced. Good stuff to know.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug. I have tried various ways to change the style without being successful. Even [example located on wxPyWiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Flatnotebook%20%28AGW%29) does not work for me when it comes to changing the styles.

I would consider asking about it on [wxPython-users mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/wxpython-users/topics).

Comment: What system/version did you try it on? I just gave it a try on Win7 with wx 2.8.12 and it doesn't work there either. I may try asking at that link, I suppose.

Comment: OS: Windows-XP-5.1.2600-SP3, Python: 2.7.1, wxPython: 2.8.12.1